# HTTP/3 request with HTTP/S or SOCKS5 proxy

Tags: go, http3, quic-go

It seems like quic-go does not support proxy for HTTP request like HTTP/2 module, how can I use HTTP/S proxy or SOCKS5 proxy with quic-go for HTTP requests?

Comment: QUIC or HTTP/3 are UDP based whereas a HTTP/S proxy is TCP and cannot transfer UDP. SOCKS5 proxy might optionally be able to transfer UDP, but this is often not implemented since not needed for the common use cases.

Answer (score 1):

The [quic-go](https://github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go) package doesn't seem to have native proxy support (it does have a class called proxy, but it appears to be a tool for testing packet loss and delays).

How about extending it yourself (or dynamically wrapping it) with [net/proxy](https://github.com/golang/net/blob/master/proxy/proxy.go) and then using this to forward your requests through a SOCKS5 proxy?